# Docker overlay network doesn't clean up removed containers

Tags: networking, nginx, docker

We're running Docker across two hosts, with overlay networking enabled and configured.  It's version 1.12.1, with Consul as the KV store - but we aren't using Swarm, largely because we didn't feel it gave us the relevant control over ensuring availability and minimising resources, but anyway.

Our setup is micro service based, and we run quite a lot of containers which get restarted fairly frequently.  Our model uses nginx as a "reverse proxy" for service discovery, for various reasons, and so we start multiple containers which share a --host of "nginx-lb".  This works fine, and other containers on the network can connect to nginx-lb, which gives them a random one of the containers' IP addresses.

The problem we have is that in killing containers and creating new ones, sometimes (I don't know what specific circumstance this occurs in), the overlay network does not remove the old container from the system, and so other containers then try to connect to the dead ones, causing problems.

The only way to then resolve this, is to manually call a `docker network disconnect -f overlay_net [container]`, having already run a `docker network inspect overlay_net` to find the errant containers.

Is there a known issue with the overlay networking not removing dead containers from the KV data, or any ideas of a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's a known issue. Follow it here https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26244